# Fuentes en angular mediante selectores

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass

Soy nuevo con este tema, no conozco mucho al respecto, estoy intentando realizar un selector en angular que cuente con diferentes tipos de fuentes, lo que deseo es que estas fuentes afecten directamente a las vistas de un proyecto.

Entiendo que se puede realizar si se pone en una carpeta los estilos directamente o bien en mi caso estoy utilizando google fonts, ambos tienen una funcionalidad similar y también su uso, lo que quiero es realizar un selector en la vista donde pueda definir la fuente que se usara, algo como lo siguiente:

```
<select class="selection" id="selection" (change)="change($event.target.value)">
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="Noto Sans">Noto Sans</option>
<select>
```

Esto lo visualizo directamente en el componente, ahí imprimo el resultado que me arroja la selección, ahora bien.

Veo que para el uso del cambio de fuentes se utiliza una propiedad que se incluye en clases o etiquetas directamente en css, intente realizar dicho dato de la siguiente manera:

```
.container
  font-family: "Nombre de la fuente" , "familia(Es un parámetro que da por defecto google fonts)"
```

Mi problema es que no encuentro una forma de hacer uso del selector y a la vez del css, algunos artículos mencionan que no se puede realizar un cambio directamente en el css, así que opte por realizar los cambios en el componente, pero no se como estar vincularlo.

Nota: Vi que es posible realizar un recorrido y llamarlo mediante sus propias clases, es decir:

```
.--Arial
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif
```

El problema es que si cambio la clase se vería afectado la vista, espero puedan apoyarme con este problema que tengo

Comment: puedes crearte una clase css para cada fuente. Y por cada cambio en el select añadir esa clase en el body.

Comment: Gracias, si es una solución que encontré, pero me gustaría en caso de ser posible una interacción entre CSS y JS

Comment: si es una interacción entre CSS y JS. Cuando cambia el valor del select tu añades la nueva clase con JS al body o donde toque